# ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

Alguém pode me ajudar com o erro abaixo:
As vezes ele aparece as vezes não , sou noob e não entendo o porque disso.

Código:

```
import math

a = float(input("digite o valor de a: "))
b = float(input("digite o valor de b: "))
c = float(input("digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b**2 - 4 *a*c
raiz_delta = math.sqrt(delta)

x1 = (-b + raiz_delta)/2*a
x2 = (-b - raiz_delta)/2*a

print("x1 e igual a ", x1)
print("x1 e igual a ", x2)
```

Erro:

```
digite o valor de a: >? 2
digite o valor de b: >? 5
digite o valor de c: >? 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/DACIO/PycharmProjects/Introducao_ao_Python_Diego_Mariano/Respostas_Curso_V2.py", line 34, in <module>
    raiz_delta = math.sqrt(delta)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Este erro está acontecento pois o valor de `delta` é negativo e não é possivel tirar a raiz quadrada de um numero negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, como comentado por outro usuário, a função `math.sqrt`está definida apenas para números positivos e, portanto, retorna um erro toda vez que delta for negativo. Existem duas soluções para seu problema. A primeira é aproveitar o seu código e incluir uma condicional. Veja:

```
import math

a = float(input("digite o valor de a: "))
b = float(input("digite o valor de b: "))
c = float(input("digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b**2 - 4 *a*c

if delta>0:
    raiz_delta = math.sqrt(delta)

    x1 = (-b + raiz_delta)/2*a
    x2 = (-b - raiz_delta)/2*a

    print("x1 e igual a ", x1)
    print("x1 e igual a ", x2)
else:
    print('Delta tem valor negativo e, portanto, as raízes da equação são números complexos')
```

A segunda opção consiste em usar a função built-in `pow` cujo domínio incluí números negativos.

```
a = float(input("digite o valor de a: "))
b = float(input("digite o valor de b: "))
c = float(input("digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b**2 - 4 *a*c

print(delta)
raiz_delta = pow(delta,0.5)

x1 = (-b + raiz_delta)/2*a
x2 = (-b - raiz_delta)/2*a

print("x1 e igual a ", x1)
print("x1 e igual a ", x2)
```